# Unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors $\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I was given that

$F(x,y,z)=\left<x+y, zx−yx, y^2-z^2\right>$

and that I needed to find the tangent, normal, and binormal vectors at $P(1, 1, 1)$.

I know that about $T(t)=F'(t)/\|F'(t)\|$, etc. But all that formulas talks about $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^m$, and my function is defined on $\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^m$; $\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$

It is possible to determine $T$, $N$, and $B$ ? And, how? Please be explicit.

Comment: The map $F$ is not a curve. So it does not make sense to talk about the tangent, normal and binormal vectors. Is there some curve you are considering? If so, please make it clear in your question.

Comment: One can in fact find $T$, $N$, and $B$ for the integral curves of the vector field $F$.  Is that what you want?